# keyboard tab button should work after loading of page in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have created a form in which many textboxes are there. I want when I click tab button it should work after loading the page, before loading the page it should not work.
please suggest how to do it.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#tab-page-loader').keydown(function (event) {
        var keyCode = event.keyCode || event.which;
        if (keyCode == 9)
        {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

I have tried this but it permanently disables the tab key

Comment: Try your code outside document ready function

Comment: `$('#tab-page-loader')` what is this? It is loader or something else?

Comment: this is Id which I have declared in form page and calling here @Manoj

Answer (score 0):

I would use tabindex for that:

[Tabindex](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_tabindex.asp)

If you want to prevent it until the page is fully loaded, add **tabindex** with **jQuery.ready** function.